# Pytorch Lightning Inference

Tags: pytorch, gpu, inference, pytorch-lightning

I trained a model using `pytorch lightning` and especially appreciated the ease of using multiple GPU's. Now after training, how can I still make use of lightnings GPU features to run inference on a test set and store/export the predictions?

The [documentation on inference](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#inference) does not target that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mind check the latest version of docs, I believe that your question is resolved there :)

Comment: @Jirka The `predict` function doesn't seem very useful, since it returns a list, rather than an iterator. So you can't use it if you are predicting on a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [`validation_epoch_end`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#validation-epoch-end) on your `LightningModule` which is called ***"at the end of the validation epoch with the outputs of all validation steps"***. For this to work you also need to define `validation_step` on that same module.

Once this is done, you can run validation using your trainer and a given dataloader by calling:

```
trainer.validate(pl_module, dataloaders=validation_dataloader)
```